# Facebook session.isOpened() always false if Facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to be able to log into Facebook by following the [Facebook Getting Started Guide.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) However a session.isOpened() call always returns false, if the Facebook App is also installed on my phone. If it is not installed on my phone everything work fine. My code is as follows:

```
public static void loginToFacebook(final Activity activity) {
  Log.d("Hello", Global.debug + " Login to Facebook");
    Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Log.d("Session Changed", Global.debug);
        if (session.isOpened()) {
          Log.d("Session Is Opened", Global.debug);
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              Log.d("Request Completed", Global.debug);
              if (user != null) {
                Log.d("Hello ", Global.debug + " " + user.getName() + "!");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Session Changed is printed to the log, but Session Is Opened never is, until I delete the Facebook app, then it prints the name associated with my Facebook account like it's supposed to after I log in. I've looked around and found that others with the same problem were using the wrong Key Hash, and found the right one by using:

```
try {
  PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.login", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
  for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.d("KeyHash:", Global.debug + " " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
  }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  Log.d("Name Not Found", Global.debug);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  Log.d("No Such Algorithm", Global.debug);
}
```

But that printed the same Key Hash that I was already using. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!